# Which pattern to use and how to use it when I have Controller, Business Logic, and Repository?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

Using MVC I have something like this:

```
class Controller
{

    //returns View
    function indexAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getData($this->id);

        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setVariable('data' => $data);

        //used to render HTML template + data above later on
        return $view;
    }


    //gets data from DB 
    //currently also does business-proprietary computation on data 
    function getData($id)
    {
        //repository/dao pattern
        $data = $this->repository->getData($id);

        //Business Logic "derivation"
        foreach ($data as $datum)
        {
            //that does not go into "Controller
            //that does not go into "Repository"
            //but where does it go? - that's my question    
            $derivedData[] = (new Business())->doLogic($datum);               
        }

        return $derivedData;
    }
}
```

**Recap**

I used Controller to get my data out of DB using Repository pattern, then placed received data into view.  But business-related computations are left stranded.

**Question**

Where do I place my business logic computations that act on the data gotten from repository?  The derived data which is to return to Controller later, to be placed into View?

Comment: In a model that is called from the controller, controllers are the glue they receive a request ( ie, $get ) and then build the return ( view ), if you have a repository that isn't directly tied to the model ( business logic ) it would retrieve the raw data into the controller which would feed it to the model, which would return it back to the controller which would generate the view.

Comment: in my case the real code of `getData` calls repository several times as part of computation.  Separating out repository data (to return to Controller) from computation part that needs it will be a tad hard but not impossible.   I wonder if I should make the whole method into a service as AsTeR have suggested, and have repository be injected into that service

Answer (score 1):

My personal choices of architecture are usually to:

- Have small controllers as thin as I can, doing only session and general right checking
- Services that are handling all business logic, one (one classe yes) per potential feature I need
- Services are querying repositories, and eventually manipulate the data in and out, but usually no Controller, nor view will do a `->save()` anywhere.
- This means that those services are usually designed to be independent from the database and easier to be tested because they only take care of one and only one task.

In your example, the whole function `getData` will be a service that I would call `GetCarDataById`. This assuming that you manipulate `Cars`, I don't like to leave `data` wandering alone.

**EDIT**: to make it clear, this kind of approach is not MVC to some definition, most people interpret MVC as putting all code either in controller, either in repositories (model). To others view, MVC doesn't mean that you have other classes, what I call services, and actually most of my code lives here.

Comment: ok, so create a new class call it `CarService`, have a method in it called `getCarDataById`, inject `CarService` into `Controller`, then from within my `indexAction` do a call `$this->carService->getCarDataById($this->id);`  Correct?

Comment: I am pretty strict on not having big class doing many things, so no I wouldn't follow what you suggest. I would have a namespace `Service\Car` and a `GetCarDataById` class inside with a `GetCarDataById` function, this way, I know that everything in a class is here to serve one, and only feature. (updated my answer). Most likely, I would in fact come to the point of having `GetCarById` and `GetCarData`, because `GetCarData` could also be something generic used by other services (to process a list of cars for example).

Answer (score 0):

The MVC pattern is clear for me.

From wikipedia:

> The model directly manages the data, logic and rules of the
>   application. A view can be any output representation of information,
>   such as a chart or a diagram. Multiple views of the same information
>   are possible, such as a bar chart for management and a tabular view
>   for accountants. The third part, the controller, accepts input and
>   converts it to commands for the model or view.

Answering your question. The modifications goes in the model domain.